# How do make my page listen to "enter" key when the form is not in a created using <form>?

Tags: angular, typescript

The HTML takes in all the output and stores them into variables inside my ts. Now there's a button (I don't know how to call it but it wasn't created in a "container" with the user inputs) that was created using  all the way at the end of the html. The button has a function that takes in the information and do what it does. So I've tested that the button is independent, and even if no user input is added, it'll still run but won't return a output. I concluded that "enter" event implementation would not be a problem. But it is not working no matter what I try.

I have tried adding the ng-keypress into the div class at the very top. I have tried putting it in the button tag. I haven't tried the directive way because I don't know where to put the directive, and most people said ng-keypress is built in directive and it should work.

'''

```
<button class="btn btn-primary float-left" (click)="submitSearch()">Search</button>

 </div>'''
```

'''

```
<button class="btn btn-primary float-left" (click)="submitSearch()"ng-keypress= "submitSearch()">Search</button>

 </div>'''
```

for the second line, i expect the ng-keypress to atleast print on console, but nothing shows up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest and most straightforward way to do with would be:

```
<div (keydown.Enter)="submitSearch()">
```

So that any form fields inside of your top-level element (in this example, this div) will capture the keydown event

Comment: thanks so much. I am new to angular and didn't know such simple solution exist. TYTYTYTY. gonna check ur answer after the cooldown ends

Answer (score 0):

try using `keydown` instead.

```
<button 
    class="btn btn-primary float-left" 
    (click)="submitSearch()"
    (keydown)= "submitSearch()"
    >Search
</button>
```

Comment: Just curious. Will a button have focus in order to capture a keydown event?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a directive and assigning that directive to the parent div/form:

```
app.directive('ngEnter', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
            if (event.which === 13) {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    scope.$eval(attrs.ngEnter);
                });
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    };
});
```

In your HTML:

```
<div ng-enter="submitSearch()">
    <input type="text" />
    ...
</div>
<button type="submit" (click)="submitSearch()">Submit</button>
```